# default DateSecondParameter in luigi (python)

Tags: python, luigi

I am working with luigi in Python and am trying to understand how luigi parameters work at compile time vs runtime.

```
import luigi
import datetime

class HelloWorld(luigi.Task):

    run_dt = luigi.DateSecondParameter(default = datetime.datetime.now())

    def requires(self):
        return(None)

    def output(self):
        return(luigi.LocalTarget('helloworld.txt'))

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('Hello World!\n')
```

I use

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

as the default DateSecondParameter in the class definition for HelloWorld(). I run the following code:

```
a = HelloWorld()
# wait a few seconds
b = HelloWorld()

a is b
'True'
```

When I pass in the current date and time as an argument I get a different result.

```
x = HelloWorld(run_dt = datetime.datetime.now())
# wait a few seconds
y = HelloWorld(run_dt = datetime.datetime.now())

x is y
'False'
```

Is the default for

```
DateSecondParameter
```

set at compile time in the class definition for HelloWorld() as opposed to when I instantiate the class? Do I need to explicitly pass in the current date and time as an argument to instantiate a unique instance?

Answer (score 1):

*Is the default for `DateSecondParameter` set at compile time in the class definition for HelloWorld() as opposed to when I instantiate the class?*

It's a little confusing to talk about compile time with Python since Python is interpreted, not compiled. The first time the class is referenced the class parameter default will be calculated.

*Do I need to explicitly pass in the current date and time as an argument to instantiate a unique instance?*

No, from the generic python perspective, each instance of the class (usually called an object) is unique. From a luigi perspective, the parameters need to differ in order for it to be considered different tasks. In the ordinary way of running luigi at the command line, each run of the worker would be a separate python process, so your code would be fine. The challenge to your approach is if you need to run many of the `HelloWorld` instances in the same worker at different times. In those cases, the task requiring the `HelloWorld` task would have to send in the now value, so it would be calculated each time the `requires()` method runs.